# Часть сложного предложения или присоединение в простом?

Tags: пунктуация

У Розенталя:

2) перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям. В качестве примера приводится, в частности, такое предложение:

Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады (Пан.);

Если говорится "между частями сложного предложения", то выходит, что "в свои, ей одной одной видимые цветущие сады" - это часть сложного предложения:"куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады"?

Часть этого "сложного"предложения после тире - это что?

На мой взгляд, слова после тире является присоединительной конструкцией в составе простого предложения "куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады". Вернее, "куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады" - часть всего сложного предложения: Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, **— верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады.***

1) Это присоединительный оборот, поясняющий наречие ***куда-то.*** Я думаю, у Розенталя в этой части текста есть неточности, но это не меняет сущности правила. Оно относится и к сложному предложению, и к частям предложения.

(п. 10.2)   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122

2) Тире здесь обозначает паузу, присоединительный оборот имеет свои знаки препинания.  Постановка тире связана с большим количеством  запятых в этом предложении.

3) Кстати, тире **стоит не во всех текстах,** в то же время постановка тире представляется оправданной, иначе грамматика предложения н прочитывается ясно.

https://detectivebooks.net/book/16509799?page=133

*Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, **верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады.***

4) В более простой конструкции возможна такая постановка знаков:

*Куда-то засмотрелась старуха, ***верно в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады.***

Здесь вводное слово не отделяется от обособленного оборота (используется в качестве присоединительного союза).